# Undefined reference to impl

Tags: c++, eclipse, sfml

I'm getting errors setting up SFML on Eclipse. I was following the instructions perfectly but I'm still getting these errors. I've tried [TDM SJLJ](http://sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.1) and [MinGW DW2](http://sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.1) - both give different undefined references.

I am linking dynamically with the sfml libraries, and I've set the path to the libraries correctly.

Here's one that I'm getting:

```
undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf6Window5closeEv' SFMLHelloWorld.cpp /SFMLHelloWorld/src line 15 C/C++ Problem
```

All of the undefined references have the prefix `_impl` on them. How do I fix this?

Comment: seems like you haven't set the library path correctly. The compiler can't find a definition to certain functions.

Comment: `I am linking dynamically with the sfml libraries`  Are these libraries `import libraries` or `static libraries`?  The `imp` in the error means `import`.  If you gave it to link to static libraries, then that is no good.  You need to provide the import libraries.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie How do I get the import libraries?

Comment: @user2030677 - The import libraries should have been provided by the author.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Where can I find them for SFML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments `_imp__` indicates that the link is looking for an imported function, meaning it's looking for a the dynamic library.

Since you simply tested both of the MinGW versions, I assume you don't understand how its supposed to work. MinGW builds are not compatible as such you need to make sure your libraries have been built with the compiler you're using for the project. The pre-built binaries on the SFML website have been built with older compiler versions and I can't advise using such an old compiler.

I suggest you get the [MinGW Builds](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/) installer to receive an uptodate compiler. Next you have to either build SFML with CMake as described in the [official tutorial](http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/compile-with-cmake.php) or if you can't get it to build properly, you can also use my [Nightly Builds of SFML](http://nightlybuilds.ch/project/show/1/SFML/), but again you need to make sure that you use the same compiler.

Comment: What do I do after I download the nightly build?

Comment: Use the [official tutorial](http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/start-cb.php) and start learning things on your own.