# Undefined reference to _imp___ on compilation

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile a game using g++ and the SFML library. It works fine on Linux, but when I try to compile on Windows, the cmd floods me with error messages that all start with "player.o:player.cpp:(.text+xxxxxx):undefined reference to _imp___..."

My makefile looks like this:

```
all:
main.o player.o simplefunctions.o
    g++ -std=c++11 main.o player.o simplefunctions.o -o climb -L C:/SFML-2.3.1/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lsfml-network

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -std=c++11 -c main.cpp -I C:/SFML-2.3.1/include

player.o: player.cpp
    g++ -std=c++11 -c player.cpp -I C:/SFML-2.3.1/include

simplefunctions.o: simplefunctions.cpp
    g++ -std=c++11 -c simplefunctions.cpp -I C:/SFML-2.3.1/include
```

.cpp -I C:/SFML-2.3.1/include

The only difference between this and my makefile I use for the same program on ubuntu is the -I and -L tags to include the library, which I don't need on linux since it gets included automatically. All the appropriate header files are also included in the appropriate cpp's.

Comment: That might be stupid, but, try to switch -lsfml-system and -lsfml-network (to understand why i suggest that, read [this](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/start-cb.php))

Comment: I gave it a shot, but the exact same error occurs.

Comment: Is the macro SFML_STATIC defined somewhere in the files?

Comment: No, where should it be defined?

Comment: It shouldn't. Well, it could but it seems that you have to link the static versions of the sfml library and their dependencies when it is defined. (if you want to try static linking, recompile the .o with -DSFML_STATIC rather than adding it to the files, but i don't think that would help)

Comment: Ya, same thing. I am beginning to hate development on windows. I wish there was a way to adapt my Linux apps to run on windows

Comment: <s>ah wait, did you try -libsfml-xxxx rather than -lsfml-xxxx? how are the library files named on windows?</s> (Edit: mmh no, stupid suggestion, nevermind)

Comment: ah, maybe you could have the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26220496/undefined-reference-to-impl (i.e. you're using the pre-built libraries, but the compiler version is different and not compatible with your libraries) anyway, if that doesn't solve the problem, try looking on/creating a topic on the [SFML forum](http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?board=4.0)

Comment: Error messages exist to a) inform the user that something went wrong and b) to inform the user what went wrong. If you try to seek help but cut off the actual error message, you're doing something wrong. Meaning: Always include the full error message of the first few errors.